# Program works in GNOME but does not work in XFCE (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: process, gnome, xfce

I wrote some C++ program, using qt and gstreamer, where I take photo from the webcam, then I open the folder with the saved image with image icon selected.

To open folder I have tried :

```
QProcess::startDetached

system()

popen()
```

I give command line to one of these functions ("nautilus ") and it opens folder with my file selected.

All these functions work perfectly on my ubuntu 12.04 with gnome, but when I try to use xfce, some problems happen: I take a photo, nautilus is opened. If I close nautilus, and take one more photo, it's okay. But when I try to take one more photo with nautilus opened, empty image file is created, and program freezes.

I tried several methods of opening nautilus, and no one works on xfce the way it must be work.

I tried to use QDesktopServices::openUrl , but this functions opens image viewing program instead of file manager , and I need to open folder with image selected.

Please someone help me.

Comment: As far as I know, the default file manager of xfce is Thunar, not Nautilus.

Comment: Yes, but if I pass to thunar the path to a file, it is opened in the image editor, it doesnot opens containing folder with selected file... if you know some command line arguments or something else to make thunar open containing folder and select a file, I will appreciate your help.